# React Native + React I18next + React Navigation, navigationOptions update issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, i18next, react-i18next

I'm using `react-i18next` and `react-navigation`.

Currently I wrap all my components with `withNamespaces` individually, when there's a need. The issue is that I can't keep the `title` in `static navigationOptions` up to date. It just doesn't update, no matter how I assign it: as a function or as properties object. The `navigation.setParams` does not update it as well.

I tried using `withNamespaces` on Navigators themselves to make use of `screenProps`, as it's done [here](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/reactnative-expo), but in this case my dispatched `NavigationActions` have no effect. The navigation just doesn't happen.

I assume that `i18next` HOC somehow prevents its children from receiving params update events. Do I need to initialise the `i18next` in some other way to resolve this? Or is there a way to force the `title` in `navigationOptions` to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I came up with a simple way to solve this. I made a component that just returns the required string, and I wrapped it with `withNamespaces` and put it into `title` prop of `navigationProperties`. Works fine.

Here's an example code.

**Title Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withNamespaces } from 'react-i18next'
import { Text } from 'react-native'

const ScreenTitle = ({ path, t }) => <Text>{t(path)}</Text>

ScreenTitle.propTypes = {
  path: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default withNamespaces()(ScreenTitle)
```

**Usage**

```
static navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    title: <ScreenTitle path="privacyPolicy:title" />,
  }
}
```

Comment: RCKT, could you add some code to show how you solved it? I'm having the same issue but I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Ok, I finally figured out you were talking about putting a component in the `headerTitle` prop, not the `title` (which only accepts strings).

Comment: @Alex, added it in my comment. In my case title accepts components. Probably because an old version of react navigation is used.

Comment: You are my hero!